# Slide up box in lower right-hand corner of page

Tags: jquery, popup, slideup

Im seeking specific instructions for creating a slide up box in the lower right-hand corner of a webpage. E.g. Olark, qualroo

Searches results have been very non specific. Bits and pieces but nothing simple and concise.

**Requirements**

- The box should be visible in a collapsed state and slide up to display a form a few seconds after a user visits the page.
- Preferably a bit of javascript that can be pasted in the footer of an existing website.

Thank you.

Comment: show your code what you have tried?

Comment: The code that I have now contains the content that would go inside of the box. Im not sure that is helpful to show since the positioning and slide up functionality of the box is the answer that I am seeking. Not sure where to begin there which is why I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create your box with css and give it position fixed to bottom right corner.
Then with jquery you can check, when user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, and do some stuff.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    // put code here to animate height and/or another css property
    // don't forget to hide box when scrolling up.
  }
});
```

Don't forget to push your box out of window by the height it has. For example if your box is 200px high, then instead of bottom 0, you'll give it -200px.

Comment: Thanks but the requirement is that the box slide up on click or a few seconds after the users has loaded the page.

Comment: Ooops sorry. Somehow I thought you were looking for a way to slide the box when scrolled down.
Anyway. You'll still have to push the box at the bottom with position fix, but instead of using the scroll code, you can do something like

    $('myBtn').click(function(){
        $('this') // if it is the box acting like a button
        $('myBox').animate({
            bottom: 0
        })
    });

And then you decide the event to animate bottom property back to original one (the one you had set from css).